# VBA code not working due to syntax error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.
My objective here is to create a function to show the lowest price of a steam item, given a URL.

Here's the mash-up code I've put together so far. However, there seems to be a problem with a syntax error.

An example URL is
http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Genuine%20Ap-Sap

I want to get the lowest price on the page to be displayed in a cell. The HTML of the page is like this. I want it to retrieve the lowest price, currently it is 9.89. I want it to show the market listing price with fee.

```
 <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
                    S&#36;9.89              </span>
                <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee">
                    S&#36;8.60              </span>
```

My VBA code follows (there is some syntex error)

```
Sub Retrieveprice() ' in the references section, enable 1) Microsoft Internet Controls, and 2) Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim x As Long, y As Long Dim htmlText As Object

Set htmlText = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", steamurl, False    ' save the URL in name manager as steamurl
    ' an example URL would be http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Genuine%20Ap-Sap
    .send
    htmlText.body.innerHTML = .responsetext End With

lStartPos = InStr(1, .responsetext, "<span class=CHR(34)market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_feeCHR(34)"> ") 
lEndPos = lStartPos + 12   'haven't counted the exact number yet, want to retrieve price
TextIWant = Mid$(.responsetext, lStartPos, lEndPos - lStartPos)   

Workbook.Worksheets.Add 
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = TextIWant  

End Sub
```

Eventually if I can get this sorted out, I want to turn it into a function, so that I can have a cell say =Retrieveprice(URL) and it to return the lowest price of the steam item on the URL.

Can someone tell me how to fix this code and turn it into a function? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: FYI, the statement for lStartPos should end as `fee" + CHR(34) + "> ")`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the `.responseText` is parsed as an `HTML` document but it can be handled with string functions as well. You seemed comfortable with `Mid`, `Instr`, etc so I stayed on that path. This does not start a new worksheet; merely writes into the current one so start on a new blank worksheet before you run the macro.

```
Sub Retrieveprice() ' in the references section, enable 1) Microsoft Internet Controls, and 2) Microsoft HTML Object Library

    Dim x As Long, y As Long, steamUrl As String, steamTxt As String, spanTxt As String, spanEndTxt As String

    steamUrl = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Genuine%20Ap-Sap"

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", steamUrl, False
        .send
        steamTxt = .responsetext
    End With

    spanTxt = "<span class=""market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"">"
    spanEndTxt = "</span>"
    x = InStr(1, steamTxt, spanTxt)
    With ActiveSheet
        Do While CBool(x)
            y = InStr(x, steamTxt, spanEndTxt)
            .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
              Application.Trim(Replace(Mid(steamTxt, x, (y - x) + Len(spanEndTxt)), Chr(10), vbNullString))
            x = InStr(y, steamTxt, spanTxt)
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

You can expect results similar to the following.

[image: msxml2.xmlhttp GET]

That's about as far as I can go with the information you've provided but it should give you a nudge in the right direction.